# What is the purpose of half- and full-width characters?

Tags: javascript, unicode, internationalization

What is the purpose of half- and full-width characters and what is the difference between them?

I am mostly curious because [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) (an open-source string validation library) has a couple of functions that evaluate the [form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) of a given input:

```
isFullWidth(str)
isHalfWidth(str)
isVariableWidth(str)
```

Why might someone want to evaluate the form of a some text?

Internally, the library uses this regex pattern to determine if the input is full-width:

```
/[^\u0020-\u007E\uFF61-\uFF9F\uFFA0-\uFFDC\uFFE8-\uFFEE0-9a-zA-Z]/
```

and this pattern to determine if the input is half-width:

```
 /[\u0020-\u007E\uFF61-\uFF9F\uFFA0-\uFFDC\uFFE8-\uFFEE0-9a-zA-Z]/
```

What is the significance of these code point ranges?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms ?

Comment: @Lashane I have read that but I do not understand.

Answer (score 4):

They're used in Asian languages. Chinese and other Hanzi-based languages have the peculiar property of forming very grid-like blocks of text, since Hanzi/Kanji are square:

> 漢字，在中國亦称中文字、中国字、方塊字，是漢字文化圈廣泛使用的一種文字，也是世界上唯一仍被廣泛使用的高度發展的語素文字。廣義的漢字指從甲骨文、大篆、金文、籀文、小篆，至隶书、草书、楷书（以及衍生的行书）等的文字，狹義指以正楷作為標準寫法的漢字，也是今日普遍使用的現代漢字。漢字在古文中只稱「字」，少數民族為區別而稱「漢字」，指漢人使用的文字。

You'll notice that even punctuation marks preserve the column-like layout of characters. Interspersing some regular half-width or dynamic-width latin will destroy that:

> 漢字，在中國亦称中文字、中国字、方塊字，是漢字文化圈廣泛使用的一種文字，也是世界上唯一仍被廣泛使用的高度發展的語素文字。Here's some irregular latin. 廣義的漢字指從甲骨文、大篆、金文、籀文、小篆，至隶书、草书 (and here's some more)、楷书（以及衍生的行书）等的文字 (and some more)，狹義指以正楷作為標準寫法的漢字，也是今日普遍使用的現代漢字。漢字在古文中只稱「字」，少數民族為區別而稱「漢字」，指漢人使用的文字。

Full-width latin characters are intended to preserve the block layout, by fitting into a Hanzi-sized square:

> 漢字，在中國亦称中文字、中国字、方塊字，是漢字文化圈廣泛使用的一種文字，也是世界上唯一仍被廣泛使用的高度發展的語素文字。Ｈｅｒｅ＇ｓ　ｓｏｍｅ　ｒｅｇｕｌａｒ　ｌａｔｉｎ．廣義的漢字指從甲骨文、大篆、金文、籀文、小篆，至隶书、草书、楷书（以及衍生的行书）等的文字，狹義指以正楷作為標準寫法的漢字，也是今日普遍使用的現代漢字。漢字在古文中只稱「字」，少數民族為區別而稱「漢字」，指漢人使用的文字。

Essentially, it just looks and reads better in this context.

Comment: Is it just me, or are the punctuation characters in your examples half-width characters?

Comment: They're "tight" commas (as opposed to the comma more common in Japan: 、), but they should be rendered full-width of a hanzi.